# How can I use C++ for the purposes of real-time audio generation in iOS?

Tags: c++, ios, swift, audio

I'm writing a simple synthesiser and sequencer for iOS.

Currently, the audio is written in Swift inside an `AVAudioSourceNode` callback.

Although it's been fun to write audio in Swift I suspect that it's inappropriate for this purpose, so I'd like to write the audio in C++ instead.

I've seen that the meat of Apple's `AudioUnit` template is written in C++, and I've noticed that AudioKit incorporates C/C++ for the purposes of audio DSP, too, so I'm sure that this is possible, but I don't know how to do it.

I would like to know how I can combine a small library of C++ classes and Swift such that my iOS app is written in Swift and its audio is written in C++.

Could you please help me to understand how this can be achieved?

Comment: Swift can't use C++ directly; you need to define a C interface that wraps your C++ as well. (What makes you think Swift is inappropriate, though? Are you having any problems?)

Comment: I see. Do you think that I would see any performance improvements by doing this? I suspect it's inappropriate because I've seen sentiment to that effect online, mostly. Apparently Apple said during WWDC17 that neither Swift nor Objective-C should be used to write audio. The CPU load of my app seems quite high, too, given how simple it is, but I don't know the degree to which this would be alleviated by writing the audio in C++ instead.

Comment: If the CPU load is unexpectedly high, then you probably should make the switch. The only way to be sure is to do both and compare.

Comment: That's certainly true. Thanks.

Comment: Look at what high performance libraries Apple is providing. Audio processing is not something you do by hand.

Comment: Audio Unit v3s are now app extensions, so they are basically delivered as part of an app. GitHub has more than a few repositories to help you get started https://github.com/topics/auv3

Comment: The core DSP of AudioUnits are indeed written in C++

Comment: And there is always JUCE as well

Comment: Thanks, @fdcpp. It looks like using AudioUnits is the way to go. It looks like the AudioUnit setup offers a lock-free, atomic way to change parameters from the UI thread, too. Nice. :)

Comment: Look at the Accelerate framework. It contains vectorized implementations for many of the building blocks you'll need for DSP operations on iOS.

Comment: Thanks @Idr. That's a good suggestion. However, despite vectorising some of the operations in Swift, the CPU usage was still very high. Using one oscillator and one lowpass filter class to feed the `AVAudioSourceNode` render callback, the CPU usage would sit between 70-90% at all times. As some have suggested in this thread, I ported the DSP to an `AudioUnit`. In my last test, I ran 32 oscillators, each with two envelopes and one lowpass filter, at 7-10% CPU usage. I can hardly believe how vast the difference is. Unfortunately the `AudioUnit` setup was quite convoluted and unpleasant.

Comment: @DavidSpry that's very interesting. Was your Swift coding using `AVAudioSourceNode` running fast enough to avoid and cracks or glitches in the audio playback? If you have any sample code showing your experiments with the oscillators, I'd be very interested to see what you did!

Comment: @DavidSpry I'm also very interested in what you did, could you provide any code example?